# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_TableA_TableC_TableCID' on table 'TableA' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

My Tables look like this:

[image: Tables]

The Corresponding models In entity framework core look like this:

```
public class TableA
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? TableBID { get; set; }
    public virtual TableB TableB { get; set; }

    public int? TableCID { get; set; }
    public virtual TableC TableC { get; set; }

    public int TableDId
    public virtual TableD TableD { get; set; }
}

public class TableB
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }

    public int TableDId
    public virtual TableD TableD { get; set; }

    //and other FKs
}

public class TableC
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public virtual TableA TableA { get; set; }

    public int TableDId
    public virtual TableD TableD { get; set; }

    //and other FKs
}
```

Relationship between TableA - TableB and TableA - TableC is one-to-one. I have defined these in OnModelCreating method in my AppDbContext class:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<TableB>()
            .HasOne(p => p.TableA)
            .WithOne(i => i.TableB)
            .HasForeignKey<TableA>(p => p.TableBID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TableC>()
            .HasOne(p => p.TableA)
            .WithOne(i => i.TableC)
            .HasForeignKey<TableA>(p => p.TableCID);
```

So, TableA has two foreign keys: `FK_TableA_TableB_TableBID` and `FK_TableA_TableC_TableCID`

When I `script keys as DROP And CREATE To New Query Editor Window`, for the first one, I get the following T-sql code:

```
USE [DDDD]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableA] DROP CONSTRAINT 
[FK_TableA_TableB_TableBID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableA]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_TableA_TableB_TableBID] FOREIGN KEY([TableBID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TableB] ([ID])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableA] CHECK CONSTRAINT 
[FK_TableA_TableB_TableBID]
GO
```

And for the second one, I get the following code:

```
USE [DDDD]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableA] DROP CONSTRAINT 
[FK_TableA_TableC_TableCID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableA]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT 
[FK_TableA_TableC_TableCID] FOREIGN KEY([TableCID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TableC] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableA] CHECK CONSTRAINT 
[FK_TableA_TableC_TableCID]
GO
```

So, because the difference between these FKs in `ON DELETE CASCADE` does that When I delete the row in TableC, the corresponding row in TableA isn't deleted.

For this reason, I tried to add `ON DELETE CASCADE` in `FK_TableA_TableC_TableCID` but I get the following error:

```
Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 7
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_TableA_TableC_TableCID' 
on table 'TableA' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON 
DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY 
constraints.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
Msg 4917, Level 16, State 0, Line 12
Constraint 'FK_TableA_TableC_TableCID' does not exist.
Msg 4916, Level 16, State 0, Line 12
Could not enable or disable the constraint. See previous errors.
```

What Can I do?

EDIT:

I want to add that for each row in TableA, one of the foreign keys are always null.

Comment: A common solution to this scenario is to use AFTER triggers to do the cascaded updates/deletes.  More flexibility that way though it takes more coding

Comment: If you have multiple 1:1 relationships perhaps you need to revisit the data architecture. That is almost always a sign that the data model is the real issue.

Comment: What would be your suggestions about the architecture?

Comment: I don't see multiple cascade paths in the posted model, and both relationships cascade delete w/o any problem. Probably you have another relationship not shown there - like common FK to user table or something like that.

Comment: @IvanStoev I edited my question.

Comment: @Sean Lange, TableB and TableC are very familiar, so I will think about it..

Comment: Ok, now you see the multiple cascade paths from D to A: (1) D -> B -> A (2) D -> C -> A (3) D -> A. So you need to turn cascade delete off for some of them until there is only one cascade path from D to A. Note that even "by your logical design" only one of the two A FKs should be specified, there is no way to let the db know that, hence the error. Btw, it is SqlServer limitation, for instance Oracle has no such issues.

Comment: Ok, Thank you, I think it would be better if change design, because TableB and TableC are very similiar..